# GWT image cropping vs. drag'n'drop problem in browser

Tags: image, gwt, drag-and-drop, crop

Using GWT, I am displaying an image on the web page and my goal is to allow the user to crop it. The user draws an imaginary boundary box by clicking on a specific part of the image, moving the mouse, and releasing it somewhere else. With the use of `MouseDownHandler()` and `MouseUpHandler()`, I am planning to record the start and end corners of the mouse cursor.

However, when I deploy my work on the web, there is this problem: When the user clicks on the image and tries to draw the imaginary bounding box, the web browser (Google Chrome in my case) detects it as a drag and drop operation.

Therefore, I cannot get my `mouseDown()` and `mouseUp()` functions to work. How can I avoid the browser to do a drag and drop operation?

The code:

```
public void onModuleLoad(){
    RootPanel.get().add(img1);

    img1.addMouseDownHandler(new MouseDownHandler() {
          @Override
          public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event) {
              startX = event.getX();
              startY = event.getY();
          }
    });

    img1.addMouseUpHandler(new MouseUpHandler() {
          @Override
          public void onMouseUp(MouseUpEvent event) {
              endX = event.getX();
              endY = event.getY();
              img1.setVisibleRect(startX, startY, endX-startX, endY-startY);
          }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think this is not possible. You will have to find an other workaround for this... I have a look on it tonight.

Comment: I have found the solution in a totally unrelated example. By adding the statement "event.preventDefault();" in the MouseDownHandler and MouseUpHandler, the drag and drop mechanism is prevented. Thanks for the ones who posted and helped out.

Comment: nice you share this with us. Didn't know you could prevent it!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use HTML5. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986418/gwt-client-side-image-crop-and-resize) earlier question here on Stack OverFlow that describes the same problem as you have. Also I found a [code example](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/wiki/gwt_hmtl5) on code.google.com
Hopefully this will lead you to an solution.